# Have an issue converting a dataframe to csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv

I have written a function to cleanup the csv file by using regex function and exporting it to csv. input fn_file for the function will take a file from a folder 'x' with a filename file.csv and process the file and exports the processed file into 'x' folder as 'file_processed.csv' .  While converting the dataframe to csv, it shows below error. How can I add header as columns to the file

```
Function
--------
process_file

Use regex to create a file with title,date and header

Parameters
----------
fn_file : str
    Name of file scraped from WDET

fn_out : str
    Name of new, reformatted, file

Returns
-------
Nothing returned. Just creates output file.

Example
-------
process_file('E:/data.csv' , 'E:/data_processed.csv')
```

## error is in the line

raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

s_df = pd.DataFrame(data = fn_file, columns = [header])

My code as given below

````py
def process_file(fn_file , fn_csv_out):

    s = re.compile(r'.*?word.+?\(\d{1,2}[ap]m-\d{1,2}[ap]m\)\s+$')

    date = re.compile(r'(Sunday)\s+(\w+\s+\d+,\s+(2010))')

    he = re.compile(r'\t\w+.\t\w+\t\w+\t\w+\s\(\w+\)\t\w+$')

    son = re.compile(r'^.*\t\d+\t.+\t')

    # Initialize counters
    num_lines = 0
    num_s = 0
    num_date = 0
    num_he = 0
    num_son = 0
    num_unmatched = 0

    # Initialize empty list to store output lines
    sonlines = []

    # Initialize string vars to use for the show title and date
    title = ''
    date = ''

    with open(fn_file) as f:

        # Loop over the lines in the file
        for line in f:

            num_lines +=1


            line = line.rstrip('\n')

            m_s = re.match(s, line)
            m_date = re.match(date, line)
            m_he = re.match(he, line)
            m_son = re.match(son, line)


            if m_s:


                num_s += 1

                # Get the show title
                ti =  m_s.group()

            elif m_date:
                # it's a date line
                num_date += 1
                show_day = m_date.group(1)
                s_date = m_date.group(2)

            elif m_he:
                # it's a header line
                num_he += 1
                heline = m_he.group()

            elif m_son:

                num_son += 1
                son_group = m_son.group()
                son = re.split(r'\t+', son_group)
                son.insert(0,ti)
                son.insert(1,s_date)
                sonlines.append(son)


    header = re.split(r'\t+',heline.rstrip('\t'))           
    header[0] = 'b'               
    header.insert(0,'ti')       
    header.insert(1,'s_date')    

    # Create pandas dataframe and export to csv

```lines throwing error
    s_df = pd.DataFrame(data = fn_file, columns = [header])
    s_df.to_csv(fn_csv_out, sep='\t', index= False)
````

```
Last two lines are throwing error, Can you please help on the error. Thanks in advance.
```

Comment: is fn_file a file path or actual data?

Comment: It is an actual data file    if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_file('data/file.csv' , 'data/file_processed.csv')

Comment: if fn_file was holding actual data, then open() would not work. you are trying to make a data frame with the data being a path to file. you need to open the file that fn_file stores the path too, and read  the data out of the file. then you can do stuff with it.

Comment: What if the fn_file is the location of the file,  as given above data is the folder where file.csv is there and I am processing file.csv and exporting the processed file into data folder as file_processed.csv

Comment: is your data supposed to be sonlines? try doing pd.DataFrame(data=sonlines, sonlines)

Comment: Perfect it works, Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved in comments. The variable was being passed to the DataFrame constructor. the fix it so change it to

`s_df = pd.DataFrame(data = sonlines, columns = [header])`

instead of

`s_df = pd.DataFrame(data = fn_file, columns = [header])`